# Car amp burned out component

Tags: amplifier, resistors, automotive

I need help identifying this component on the board of my car amp that has burned out. Electronic circuit board knowledge is pretty much zero for me. But I’m good at fixing stuff so I want to try to repair this if possible. The component in question is a little brownish square. It looked like the 2 brown squares next to each other in the pics. Is it a resistor and where can I find this ? Also is the burn on the board too much to re-solder a replacement ? I apologize if I’m asking in the wrong place but maybe someone can point me in a direction here..
Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are the symptoms when the amp is powered up?

Comment: I am having some trouble reading its label.

Answer (score 1):

The brown squares are ceramic capacitors. Judging from the photo and your analysis that it was a brown square, the burnt component was an input filter capacitor for a switch mode DC/DC converter.

Without a service manual to provide schematics or a component list, it is impossible to determine what will be a suitable replacement capacitor.

There is also a lot of PCB damage, the conductors are burnt off so there is nothing left to solder the capacitor.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Justme, yea I kinda thought the PCB looked pretty bad there but it looks like the end of the conductor is showing and the other side still has a piece of the old capacitor in place. I guess I could clean it up and try re soldering the replacement.  from what Spehro is saying I could try a 22uf 10v capacitor and that’s all I can do I guess to see if it works. Thanks a lot anyways I definitively found my answer :) eureka it’s a capacitor! And dear admin, my apologies again for being off topic and thanks for letting me have the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

So it appears to have been a capacitor. It's possible it was a ceramic capacitor , perhaps in parallel with that 47uF 6V capacitor. So you could try a 22uF/10V ceramic capacitor, if it buzzes out in parallel.

But maybe something else serious is wrong as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the responses guys! Will try to replace that capacitor Spehro, hopefully with success. I know there could be something else wrong that caused the burn in the first place but I’ll give it a shot..